# where can I delete the password cache in krusader in xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, password-recovery, krusader

I have installed krusader under Xubuntu and there I stored an ssh-password in the cache.

Now the password changed, and I have no option to re-enter the password.
krusader only tells me, that the authentification failed.

Where do I find the kde security center in Xubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't know if Krusader uses a different password store in XFCE or any non-KDE environment, but in KDE it saves passwords in the KDE Wallet. Anyway, you could try to see if you find your password there.

You can start the Waller Manager by running `kwalletmanager` at a terminal or using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. A window should open that will show your wallet; click it to open it in a new window.
In the wallet window, search for your ssh connection (or something like that) in the top text box, or expand Passwords -> Maps in the left tree. If you find your entry, just right-click it and choose Delete.

If the Waller Manager shows more than one wallet, you can find in the KDE System Settings which one is the default. Run `systemsettings` and go to "Account Details" -> "KDE Wallet"; the default wallet should be selected in a combo box labeled "Select wallet to use as default".

Of course, if there is no `kwalletmanager` in your system or you can't find your password in there, then Krusader must be storing them elsewhere.

Comment: I had to install it with `sudo apt-get install kwalletmanager` then it was there in systemsettings